# Определить пользователя без cookie

Tags: ip, сессия, cookie

Суть такова, нужно определить пользователя даже если он удалил cookies
и посчитать количество попыток логинизации.. в случае превышения - дать отдохнуть пользователю минут 5..

мысли следующие..
установить в имя сессии md5 ip адреса и там считать,
если у пользователя нет cookies то определить его ip и соответствие сессии.
сессии живут час

Comment: Не, по IP не катит. Если из VPN на твой сайт заходят несколько человек?

Comment: Ясное дело, защита от обычных смертных, но, например, делать хеш из микса айпишника и агента - уже хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем md5? просто запиши ip и счетчик попыток логина пользователя во временную таблицу.
ip превысил придел => сообщение о бане на 5 минут
5 минут прошли => обнуляешь счетчик попыток и снова логин

Все это реализуется на сервере, а все что ты установишь в куки может быть изменено, удалено и так далее.

Comment: Если у пользователя который ранее залогинился на сайте такой-же IP адрес как и у меня (с одной подсети входим), то как сайт поймёт кто входит? Если сайт работает в сети в которой невозможно такое стечение обстоятельств то вперёд, иначе наверное только если Java-апплетом писать файлик на диск юзеру, но это не красиво. Cookies для решения авторизации на сайте и предназначаются, а подобные костыли только усугубляют проблему безопастности.

Comment: ну а каким способом тогда решить проблему..
пользователь сбросил куки и пошел брутить заново..
базу использовать нельзя..будет много запросов.. при каждой попытке логина и т.д. сильно нагрузит систему..

микс из агента и ip..  у меня дома три компа.. вывод все будут отдыхать 5 минут если один из компов олень.. 
нужны другие способы..подскажите куда копать..

Comment: На сколько я помню в PHP с адресами все в порядке, там есть 
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] и $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] они тебе оба понадобятся.
А если без базы данных, где ты количество попыток собираешься хранить ? Тоже в сессии ?

Answer (score 0):

Соответствие ip и UserAgent?

Comment: насколько понял можно сделать следующим образом.. записывать данные в таблицы ipfw (freebsd) и тупо банить все пакеты юзера по превышении..